# SQLite select statement is not working when a column contains the '?' or the 'x' character

Tags: android, sqlite

I noticed that whenever I try to execute an sqlite query on a column that contains strings in which the '?' (due to encoding errors) or the 'x' character is contained, the matching fails. 
Does anyone know why? I suspect the second case has something to do with the relative hexadecimal symbol. This holds for either sqlite version 3.7.9 and 3.8.6. 
Thanks in advance

Edit:
`SELECT FM.Foodname FROM Foodtable AS FM WHERE Foodname MATCH 'Alom*' UNION ALL SELECT F2.Foodname FROM Foods_units_2 AS F2 JOIN Foodtable ON Foodtable.Foodname = F2.Foodname ORDER BY F2.Foodname;`
The problem is withe last statement (Foodtable.Foodname = F2.Foodname) where the Foodtable contains all records and Foods_units_2 contains part of records with different units of measurement. In both tables there are Foodname strings that contain the characters '?' (due to encoding errors) and 'x'. In thoses cases the matching fails and sqlite replaces the wrong strings with others

For example in the first case I have "Cr?me Kαραμελέ" where '?' is supposed to be 'è' and in the second case "4?4 compact" where '?' is supposed to be 'x'.

Comment: Please, attach your SQL requests

Comment: I think you should consider cleaning the DB before using it.

Comment: @Mundi - Isn't there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Show some records that you think should match, but don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I made a mistake. The reason the matching failed was because the main table included records where '?' was present (encoding errors), while Foods_units_2 table did not.

Anyway, hank you guys for your promptness and sorry for the inconvenience.